# Node.js and MongoDB on MongoLab: "Sockets Closed" On Every Insert

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sockets, azure, mlab

I'm trying to do something relatively simple and am running into a "server ...-a.mongolab.com:36648 sockets closed" error all of a sudden every time I try to do an "insert".

Reads seem to work without error, but inserts seem to get an error *every* time and I'm not sure if it's my code (which recently underwent minor changes), or a reliability problem with the free server I'm using at MongoLab (which recently showed itself to be down for a few minutes).

Oddly enough, the record itself seems to save okay, I just get the error back!

Can anyone see an issue with my code, or could this be something else?

```
var mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var http = require('http');

var connectionString = "...";
var pictureWallsCollectionName = 'PictureWalls';

//this is what barfs. see *** details
exports.saveWall = function (req, res) {
    //reformat
    var toSave = {
        _id: req.body.wallId,
        pictures: req.body.pictures
    };

    var status;

    mongoClient.connect(connectionString, function (err, db) {
        if (err) { return console.error(err); }

        var collection = db.collection(pictureWallsCollectionName);

        //*** no err yet... ***
        collection.insert(
            toSave, 
            function (error, response) {
                //*********************
                //*** err here!  ******
                //*********************
                db.close();
                if (error) {
                    console.error(error);
                    //bad
                    status = 500;
                }
                else {
                    console.log('Inserted into the ' + collection_name + ' collection');
                    //good
                    status = 200;
                }
            });

        response.status(status).end(http.STATUS_CODES[status]);
    });
}

//this seems to work pretty reliably. including it just in case it's relevant
exports.findByWallId = function (req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    console.log('Retrieving wall: ' + id);

    mongoClient.connect(connectionString, function (err, db) {
        if (err) { return console.dir(err); }

        var collection = db.collection(pictureWallsCollectionName);
        collection.findOne(
            { _id: id }, 
            function (err, item) {
                db.close();
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                    //something bad happened
                    var status = 500;
                    res.status(status).end(http.STATUS_CODES[status]);
                }
                else {                    
                    console.log('Found wall with ID ' + id);
                    //reformat and send back in the response
                    res.send({
                        wallId: item._id,
                        pictures: item.pictures
                    });
                }
            }
        );
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Part of my original issue was duplicate parameter names. See the linked question for detail.

ORIGINAL RESPONSE:
The issue ended up being that I was calling:

```
 res.status(status).end(http.STATUS_CODES[status]);
```

...before the async insert was finished, so it barfed.

However, I'm not exactly sure how to issue the response in this case. See my new question here:

[How Do I Properly Issue Response To Post When Waiting For Async Method To Complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31821703/how-do-i-properly-issue-response-to-post-when-waiting-for-async-method-to-comple)