# How do I properly issue response to post when waiting for async method to complete?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here's the setup in a module. See, esp., comments marked by ****:

```
exports.saveWall = function (req, res) {
    var status;

    mongoClient.connect(connectionString, function (err, db) {
        if (err) { return console.dir(err); }

        db.collection(pictureWallsCollectionName).insert(
            { _id: req.body.wallId, pictures: req.body.pictures }, 
            function (err, res) {   
                db.close();
                if (err) {
                    status = 500;
                    console.dir(err);
                }
                else {
                    status = 200;
                    //*****can't do this here, because res is out of scope!
                    res.status(status).send(http.STATUS_CODES[status])
                    console.log('Inserted into the ' + pictureWallsCollectionName + ' collection');                     
                }
            });      
    });

    //*****can't do this yet because the above isn't done.
    res.status(status).send(http.STATUS_CODES[status])
}
```

I basically want to call the line `res.status(status).send(http.STATUS_CODES[status])` in my callback, but I can't because res.status is null at that point.

All I want to do is respond to a POST, but I am not getting anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you solved your scope issue (which is awesome), nesting callbacks can get kind of tricky quickly (as you saw).  A good way to deal with this is to use promises.  The two main packages for promises are [Q](https://www.npmjs.com/package/q) and [Bluebird](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bluebird) (with Bluebird being my favorite).

You can also use a package that has already promise-ified mongo calls for you, like [promised-mongo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promised-mongo)

Once you have that all set up, it's just a matter of chaining `.then` for successive steps, and then sending your response when the promise is resolved.

For a specific example, check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23597059/promise-and-nodejs-mongodb-driver) and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Ugh...

It turns out my issue was that "res" was defined both here:

```
exports.saveWall = function (req, res) {
```

...and here:

```
db.collection(pictureWallsCollectionName).insert(..., 
        function (err, res) {
```

...so it turns out I could call "res" all along, I was just trying to call the wrong "res" because it got redefined.

On a side note, f*** you, javascript!

Comment: I was mid-writing an answer, but I'm glad you fixed your issue.  You might look into promises to deal with this type of thing, especially if you have a bunch of logic on success.  I've use the bluebird package for node and I like it quite a bit.  Good luck!